# undefined method in ActionView (rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method in my application helper but for some reason it isn't being found when I run my rspec tests. Here's the error:

```
Failure/Error: helper.chart_series(user).should =~ /y: 100/
     undefined method `ab_variant' for #<ActionView::Base:0x102b12d78>
     # ./app/helpers/sidebar_helper.rb:17:in `chart_series'
     # ./spec/helpers/sidebar_helper_spec.rb:35
```

How do i make sure ab_variant (within application helper) can be found by my rspec tests?

Answer (score 0):

Your helpers defined in app/helpers aren't loaded in rspec by default. You have to re-create them.

So create a file and call it a name you like, for ex. "application_helper.rb" and place it inside spec/support. This will be included automatically and will be available in your specs by this file in spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```